# jquery.jqGrid.src.js CDN not find in latest versions of jQuery, what we can use instead of this from 4.6.0 next onwards

Tags: jquery

I am upgrading my jQuery Grid from 4.6.0 to 5.7.0. I got all the files from https://cdnjs.com/libraries/jqgrid/5.7.0 except this jquery.jqGrid.src.js.
If I use 4.6.0 version .src.js file, I got below error in console.
Uncaught Type Error: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'integer')

Can anyone help me to resolve this error.
Thank you.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: While using jqGrid, what are the CDNs, we must include in our HTML file